# entityframework clone or copy an entity instance to another object

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am working on an asp.net mvc core 2.0 project and entityframework.

I am working with viewmodel concept.

This mean i do not pass entities instances directly to my view, i pass a viewmodel instance which only contains what the view needs.

in one case, i need to pass the entire entity fields plus other informations.

What i've done is a derivated my ViewModel class from my Entity Class. and i add the extra fields:

```
public MyViewModel: Person
{
    // I will automaticly have Person fields in MyViewModel
    public bool IsSelected {get;set;}
    public String otherinformation {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

I am fed up with assigning each fields of my viewmodel from my entity instance.

```
myviewmodelinstance.field1 = myentity.field1;
myviewmodelinstance.field2 = myentity.field2;
myviewmodelinstance.field3 = myentity.field3;
myviewmodelinstance.IsSelected = false;
...
```

And i need to do the inverse operation in the postback.

Is there a way to "copy" or "clone" every fields, like this:

```
myentity.CopyTo(myviewmodelinstance);
myviewmodelinstance.IsSelected = false;
```

Thanks

Comment: I believe you need something like AutoMapper for that. Have a look at https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Comment: Yes, automapper. Good 8 minute video [here](https://wildermuth.com/2015/07/22/Mapping_Between_Entities_and_View_Models)

Comment: Why is there nothing built-in by Microsoft ? Is it a good practice ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `AutoMapper` to achieve it. It is the ideal way to perform it. Another option is that you can serialize and deseriliaze the object as json.

```
var myviewmodelinstance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyViewModel>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myentity));
```

Note : The code I provided required `Json.Net`